# VCR does not record cassettes using faraday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, faraday, vcr

I have scoured the internet for an answer to this, including most of the other "suggested" questions on SO.

I have configured VCR in rspec, but when running the tests VCR never records a tape (tape dir remains empty) and runs the HTTP request every time.

My VCR config looks like this:

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.cassette_library_dir = Rails.root.join('spec', 'vcr_cassettes')
  c.hook_into :faraday
  c.default_cassette_options = { record: :new_episodes }
  c.configure_rspec_metadata!
  c.allow_http_connections_when_no_cassette = true
  c.ignore_hosts 'api.linkedin.com'
  c.debug_logger = $stderr
end
```

I am using `faraday` because the LinkedIn gem I am using (https://github.com/bobbrez/linkedin2) is using `faraday` to make requests already. The test spec I'm running looks like this:

```
describe API::V1::Connections, type: :request do
  subject { LinkedIn::Client.new scope: %i(r_network) }

  describe 'GET /api/v1/connections/:username', vcr: { cassette_name: 'profile' } do
    it 'fetches the user profile' do
      profile = subject.profile
      expect(profile).not_to be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

It passes each time, but only after making the API request every time. The VCR debug log shows the **exact** same thing on every run of the spec:

```
[Cassette: 'profile'] Initialized with options: {:record=>:new_episodes, :match_requests_on=>[:method, :uri, :headers], :allow_unused_http_interactions=>true, :serialize_with=>:yaml, :persist_with=>:file_system}
[faraday] Handling request: [get https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(connections)?oauth2_access_token=xxxx&format=json {"User-Agent"=>["Faraday v0.9.0"]}] (disabled: false)
[faraday] Identified request type (ignored) for [get https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(connections)?oauth2_access_token=xxxx&format=json {"User-Agent"=>["Faraday v0.9.0"]}]
```

It seems like it should record a cassette, but no `.yml` files ever show up in the `spec/vcr_cassettes` dir

(Using Rails 4, rspec 3, vcr 2.9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've configured VCR to ignore requests made to `'api.linkedin.com'` with this line:

```
c.ignore_hosts 'api.linkedin.com'
```

...which prevents it from recording those requests.

Comment: Yes, for some reason I was under the impression that the ignore_hosts options only allowed requests to that URL. Clearly I didn't read carefully enough. Thanks for pointing this out.